# Is libodbc++ dormant? Is there any explicit successor?

Tags: c++, sql-server, windows, odbc, dbf

I am searching for a C++ library that wraps ODBC. To follow the SO rules about avoiding "opinionated" questions. So, is the libodbc++ project dormant (http://libodbcxx.sourceforge.net/libodbc++/roadmap.html) or is it simply "without bugs" and it need not to be changed since the last version?

If it is abandoned, is there any direct successor?

**Context:** I have two main Windows desktop applications based on DBF files (FoxPro drivers). The older one uses MDAC with vfpodbc driver, the newer uses OLE DB (ATL objects with vfpodbc driver). The successor should use MS-SQL, and I also want to switch from OLE DB to the now more supported (by Microsoft) ODBC. I am also searching for the library that can be used not only for Windows applications (cross platform).

Comment: I hope this is not against the rules of stackoverflow as it is some sort of advertising: I've been working on a odbc-lib for fun (whats funnier than odbc :P ) and just some days ago I've put something online. Its far away from being complete, but its free and open source, so I'll just add a link here: https://exodbc.elisium.ch/trac - give it a try if you like, complain if it wont work - extend if you like.

Comment: @erg: Nice. I will look at it later. Actually, I was thinking also about wxODBC that is deprecated now. As I like wxWidgets. By the way, do you know the Catch testing framework for C++? https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/

Comment: Not known so far about Catch, but I like this sentence from the doc: Failures can (optionally) break into the debugger on Windows and Mac.
Currently I'm using google test together with the 'Google Test Runner' addon for Visual Studio, so that the google tests integrate nicely into visual studio.

Comment: Is there a chance to make your library ready (simple) for the "UTF-8 Everywhere Manifesto" http://utf8everywhere.org/ ?

Comment: To be honest, I dont know if thats possible (or how complicated): All the windows SQL functions are defined to the wchar_t implementations if _UNICODE is defined. If _UNICODE is not defined they expect only ascii chars (or so).
It is of course possible to read unicde-data stored in the database into a unicode SQLCHAR array - I think most drivers should support that. For example if reading Varchar data from DB2 it will sometimes use two or more SQLCHAR values for one character. But you would then still need some other function that converts this utf-8 string to your (wstring) windows-locale..

Comment: I even dont know if windows actually supports utf-8 codepages? So you probably could use utf-8 internally everywhere, but as soon as it comes to calling windows sql functions you would have to convert the utf-8 to the current windows locale..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in https://lexicalunit.github.io/nanodbc/

Its GitHub repository is here https://github.com/lexicalunit/nanodbc